# How to remember form values after startup using c#?

Tags: c#

I have an application and I save the form values in xml file, but it works only while computer is ON. I want to do a auto-run application, the user put the values once and forever Works after that with these values. I already registered my application for auto-run in startup but when the application run after the startup, forget all values. In my form principal I put this code, the archive exists but the application only read it while PC do not turn off, I want that program read after startup:

```
        InitializeComponent();


        if (File.Exists("data.xml") && File.Exists("data2.xml"))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Information));
            FileStream read = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Information info = (Information)xs.Deserialize(read);
            if (!info.Data1.Equals("") || !info.Data4.Equals(""))
            {
                if (!info.Data3.Equals("") && !info.Data3.Equals("10"))
                {
                    timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(info.Data3) * 60 * 1000;
                }
                else if (!info.Data6.Equals("") && !info.Data6.Equals("10"))
                {
                    timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(info.Data6) * 60 * 1000;
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Interval = 600000;
                }
                timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                FormInicial fi = new FormInicial();
                fi.Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FormInicial fi = new FormInicial();
            fi.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you save user settings ? you can register to OnClose event and than keep the settings before the form is close

Comment: Sure, this is not correct code.  **Always** use full path names for files.  Like c:\foo\bar\data.xml, not just data.xml.  Your code is unlikely to work correctly when you start it in an unusual way, the Environment.CurrentDirectory won't be where you hope it is.  Use the appdata folder, Environment.GetFolderPath() to retrieve it.